# How to render base64 image as pdf using visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, renderas

I see many posts that it is not possible to render base64 image as pdf in visualforce page, is it still possible ? This image is coming from another system and I do not want to store in sf as an attachment instead directly render as pdf.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:image value="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...." alt="" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will never work until/unless the underlying PDF rendering engine, Flying Saucer, is updated to included support for this feature. As far as I'm aware, there's no plans to include a more capable PDF engine. We have two rendering systems available, `pdf` and `advanced_pdf`, neither of which support data URL  images.